# Glossaries: the page number appear at a wrong position

Tags: longtable, glossaries

I use the glossaries package like this:

```
\usepackage[toc,xindy]{glossaries}
\include{glossaryentries}
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill}
\makeglossaries

....

\setglossarystyle{long}
\printglossary[title=List of Notations]
```

and get that

[image: the page number on the 4th line on the left should be on the 3rd line on the right]

It does exactly what I want, except for some entries like the second one on the picture, where the page number appear on the left instead of the right.
I have no idea why. 
Does someone know what I should do?

This specific entry is described by

```
\newglossaryentry{supportfunction}{
   name         ={\ensuremath{h(K, \vect{u} )}},
   description  ={support function of $K$ evaluated in the direction $ \vect{u} $},
   sort         =hKu
   }
```

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{supportfunction}{
  name          ={\ensuremath{h(K, \boldsymbol{u} )}},
  description   ={support function of $K$ evaluated in the direction $ \boldsymbol{u} $},
  sort          =hKu
  }

\begin{document}
  \gls{supportfunction}
  \setglossarystyle{long}
  \printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, make a minimal example, but also try `\dotfill\nolinebreak`

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your comment. `\nolinebreak` works. Problem solved :-) You can post it as an answer if you wish.

Comment: Not without a full (minimal) example that shows the issue.

Comment: @egreg Sorry for my laziness of not having provided a minimal example earlier. Shame on me. I just added one to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be reproduced by explicitly using `longtable`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lp{\glsdescwidth}}
\ensuremath{h(K, \boldsymbol{u} )} &
support function of $K$ evaluated in the direction
$ \boldsymbol{u} $\dotfill\space
1\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This is essentially what the `long` style does. The problem seems to be the space after `\dotfill`. Since this is part of the style, the simplest solution is to define a custom style based on `long`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{longdotted}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\dotfill ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\newglossaryentry{supportfunction}{
  name          ={\ensuremath{h(K, \boldsymbol{u} )}},
  description   ={support function of $K$ evaluated in the direction
$ \boldsymbol{u} $},
  sort          =hKu
  }

\begin{document}
  \gls{supportfunction}
  \setglossarystyle{longdotted}
  \printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]